# OpenCart css a.clicked shows and disappears

Tags: html, css, opencart

Using OC v1.5.6.4
**I wish to keep css state for header menu as Clicked after clicked**

I have this going as menu:

```
<div id="m">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Store</a>
        <div>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Man</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Woman</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

With **css** so:

```
#m > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
#m > ul > li:hover > a {
    color:#000 !important;
}
#m > ul >  li > a.clicked {
    color: #823428;
    border-bottom: #823428 2px solid !important;;
}
#m > ul > li > div > ul > li > a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

I have jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("a").click(function(e) {
    $("a", $("#menu")).each(function () {
        if( $(this).hasClass("clicked") )
            $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    });

    $(this).addClass("clicked");
    });
});
```

When link is clicked before releasing mouse button it does turn to a.selected
But after mouse click released it does not save class state.

What am I doing wrong?? Is it the page reloading??
Example:

[Working example - not working](http://newebgen.com/index.php?route=common/home)

[jsfiddle - working great](http://jsfiddle.net/jadeye26/HDcqr/33/)

Comment: Thank you all...this led me to the solution with jQuery: Solution can be seeing here:                                  http://jsfiddle.net/jadeye26/HDcqr/33/          $("a").click(function(e) {
    $("#m > ul > li > a").each(function () {
        if( $(this).hasClass("clicked") )
            $(this).removeClass("clicked");
    });
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});

Answer (score 0):

nothing. that's exactly what `a:active` does

> The :active selector is used to select and style the active link.
>
> A link becomes active when you click on it.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding links to w3schools which contains lots of outdated an inaccurate information...

Comment: It is common knowledge. W3Schools is awful. A few years ago I picked a page at random from it and found that half the paragraphs there contained misleading information and the other half contained something that was outright wrong.

Comment: Take the bit you quoted, for example. It fails to mention that `:active` doesn't apply only to links, it doesn't mention the condition for the link to no longer be active, and it doesn't mention that the active state can be triggered with the keyboard.

Comment: This is the official ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes 

"*The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user. For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it.*"

Answer (score 0):

The `:active` state will not remain after clicking.

If you want the link to remain the same color as the `:active` state, or become a different color, you'll want to use the `:visited` state.

```
#m > ul >  li > a:visited {
    color: #823428;
}
```